# How to make Hot reload works with dockerized vue3 and vite

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, docker-compose, vuejs3

I have a problem concerning my dockerized app in vue3 using vite.

First I made the production environment which works perfectly using docker

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ../ /app
RUN npm run build

# Production
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

After this I have made my docker-compose file which contain only this

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d` it works perfectly on `localhost:8080` but I have a problem, hot reload is not working anymore for local development purpose so I have to build another time my app to see live result.

How can I achieve this ?

Here is my vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Can you `npm run dev` or similar, to get a live-reloading setup that doesn't involve Docker?  A setup based on serving a prebuilt application via Nginx is an excellent production-oriented setup, but it's hard to use for day-to-day development.

Comment: I understand also for example using npm run dev inside my docker app ? But can't use npm command, it's not recognized .. I would like to have the development environment as close as possible to the production environment in order to avoid little mistakes..

Comment: These different modes exist for a very good reason.  You can't expect development features with production builds because the builds are _meant for production_: your code becomes minified and specific debugging tools and error logging are turned off.  development mode _is meant for development_.  You can trust that your production build will match your dev build only with development specific features disabled. Containerizing your app in docker is also a production step and unnecessary for actual development.